# Approximating an Integral on a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, approximation

Let $(M,g)$ be a (relatively compact) oriented (sub-)riemannian manifold without boundary. Let $d$ be the induced riemannian metric. I am looking for some constants $m,n,c,\epsilon>0$, such that for all $\delta\in(0,\epsilon)$ and $p\in M$
$$\int_M d(p,q)^m e^{-d(p,q)/\delta}dVol(q)\leq c\delta^{n+1}.$$

Is it also possible to get that type of approximation on an arbitrary metric measure space?

I would appreciate any idea how to tackle this approximation. This looks somehow like a gamma function, but since I never worked with them I was a bit lost in literature.

Comment: What does relatively compact mean?

Comment: The closure of it would be compact.

Comment: You can't take the closure unless $M$ is a subset of another set.

Comment: Yes, thats true. Describing it as submanifold would have been better, but i thought i could streamline the question with that. Didn't think of it thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $m$, note
$$ e^{-x} = \frac{1}{e^x} \le \frac{1}{x^m/m!}=\frac{m!}{x^m},$$

we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{M} d(p, q)^m e^{-d(p, q)/\delta} dV&\le m! \int_M d(p, q)^m \frac{\delta ^m }{d(p, q)^m} dV \le m! \operatorname{Vol}(M) \delta^m.
 \end{align*}

Obviously the above works whenever $(M, d)$ is a measure metric space with finite measure.